# conversion of datetime datatype to date and time datatype in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, time

I am a newbie. I started php coding few days back. I want to copy a "datetime" datatype in php to fields that are of "date" and "time" datatype.

I have kept the field name datetime_info for the datetime value. It exists in try1 table. date is the name of field for "date" datatype and time is the name for "time" datatype. These two exist in try2 table.

Here is what I have written.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM try1");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $result_update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO try2 (date, time) VALUES ('".$row_team['datetime_info']."', '".$row_team['datetime_info']."')");
    if (!$result_update)
    die('Error: ' . mysql_errno() . mysql_error());
}
```

The values stored in "try1" table are:

```
id  datetime_info
1   2008-10-02 00:00:00
2   2008-10-09 00:00:00
```

The expected response should be the date and time stored in respective fields. However, the output is

```
id  date        time
2   0000-00-00  00:00:00
3   0000-00-00  00:00:00
```

Can anyone explain me why and how? I tried a lot of sites but did not find any proper explanation for this. Thank you in anticipation.

Regards,
BasicGem

Comment: See also `MySQLi` http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't have to use PHP to do the hard work here. MySQL is very powerful to do these kinds of tasks on it's own.

Since you are copying all rows from table `try1` into `try2` (but splitting the datetime column), the following should work:

```
INSERT INTO
  `try2`
  SELECT
    null, DATE( `datetime_info` ), TIME( `datetime_info` )
  FROM
    `try1`
```

What this does is: for every record found in `try1` insert the following values into `try2`:

- `null` means use the `auto_increment` functionality of the `id` column in `try2` (this is presuming the `id` column is indeed an auto incrementing primary key field)
- `` DATE( `datetime_info` ) `` means use the DATE part of the `datetime_info` column of `try1`
- `` TIME( `datetime_info` ) `` means use the TIME part of the `datetime_info` column of `try1`

Simply doing `mysql_query( $sql )` where `$sql` is a string that represents above query should suffice then. No need to loop through any results first with PHP.

I was gonna write a PHP solution as well, but others have already done so. I would have suggested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647606/conversion-of-datetime-datatype-to-date-and-time-datatype-in-php-mysql/7647685#7647685).

Comment: Just wondering, what would this 'null' insert into 'try2'? Would it retain the first column as primary key value or put 'NULL'??

Comment: @GhazanfarMir: I was already updating my answer with some additional explanation. Hope this explains it well enough. If not: please let me know.

Comment: Coool - thanks for the clarification. Just spotted a wrong function name in 3rd bullet. It should be `TIME` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM try1");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $split = explode(' ', $row_team['datetime_info']);

   $result_update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO try2 (date, time) VALUES ('". $split[0]."', '".$split[1]."')");
    if (!$result_update)
    die('Error: ' . mysql_errno() . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you so much Mir :)

Answer (score 1):

Because your taking it into a format and pushing it to fit another one.
Just use `explode()` and you'll have the 2 parts you need.

```
list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $row_team['datetime_info']);
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks a lot :) Just for clarification, we can use explode and it will automatically split the required data using ' ' as delimiter. correct?

Comment: @BasicGem: correct. You know where you can find the manual to read more about this function?

Answer (score 0):

Field of type `date` stores the date information, meaning year, month and day (in that order).
`time` field, as you might have guessed, stores time information in format of hour:minute:second.

If you take a look at what you did, which is inserting a `datetime` into `date` field and `time` field respectively - MySQL doesn't recognize the format (you are passing the data in the wrong format that's expected for `date` or `time` field), hence it stores it as default date value.

You need to parse the output of `datetime_info` column into the date part and time part and then feed it to mysql.

Comment: That is true. I used the above mentioned explode examples and it worked fine. Thanks for your help N.B. :)